# Concatenate gsub

Tags: regex, r, optimization, gsub

I'm currently running the following code to clean my data from accent characters:

```
df <- gsub('Á|Ã', 'A', df)
df <- gsub('É|Ê', 'E', df)
df <- gsub('Í',   'I', df)
df <- gsub('Ó|Õ', 'O', df)
df <- gsub('Ú',   'U', df)
df <- gsub('Ç',   'C', df)
```

However, I would like to **do it in just one line** (using another function for it would be ok). How can I do this?

Comment: The “real” way to do this doesn’t involve regular expressions but rather Unicode normalisation. However, I’m not sure how well supported Unicode library bindings (such as ICU) are in R, and thus how practically feasible a proper solution would be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this

```
iconv(c('Á'), "utf8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT")
```

You can just add more elements to the `c()`.

EDIT: it is machine dependent, check `help(iconv)`

Here is the `R` solution

```
mychar <- c('ÁÃÉÊÍÓÕÚÇ')
iconv(mychar, "latin1", "ASCII//TRANSLIT") # one line, as requested
[1] "AAEEIOOUC"
```

Comment: This returns `NA` for me.

Comment: This should do it `mychar <- c('Á', 'Ã', 'É', 'Ê', 'Í',  'Ó', 'Õ', 'Ú','Ç')`  `iconv(mychar, "latin1", "ASCII//TRANSLIT")`

Comment: Yeah, on Windows you should use something like "ISO-8859-1" instead of "utf8".

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but it only seems to work with single vectors. I actually have to read a names vector with 900 entries, and I can't just shove the whole vector into `iconv`.

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio sure you can: `Vectorize(iconv)(rep(mychar, 2), "latin1", "ASCII//TRANSLIT")`

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio Update your question with a more accurate example of your real use-case. `sapply` might be part of the solution.

Comment: or even `paste(mychar,collapse=`) if you know a good separator.

Comment: Nevermind, halfway through creating a loop here I found out I had typed the wrong vector name. `iconv` works fine with vectors, real sorry. :$

Answer (score 3):

It an encoding problem, Normally you resolve it by indicating the right encoding. If you still want to use regular expression to do it , you can use `gsubfn` to write one liner solution:

```
library(gsubfn)
ll <- list('Á'='A', 'Ã'='A', 'É'='E',
           'Ê'='E', 'Í'='I', 'Ó'='O',
           'Õ'='O', 'Ú'='U', 'Ç'='C')
gsubfn('Á|Ã|É|Ê|Í|Ó|Õ|Ú|Ç',ll,'ÁÃÉÊÍÓÕÚÇ')
[1] "AAEEIOOUC"
gsubfn('Á|Ã|É|Ê|Í|Ó|Õ|Ú|Ç',ll,c('ÁÃÉÊÍÓÕÚÇ','ÍÓÕÚÇ'))
[1] "AAEEIOOUC" "IOOUC"
```

Answer (score 1):

One option could be `chartr`

```
> toreplace <- LETTERS
> replacewith <- letters
> (somestring <- paste(sample(LETTERS,10),collapse=""))
[1] "MUXJVYNZQH"
> 
> chartr(
+   old=paste(toreplace,collapse=""),
+   new=paste(replacewith,collapse=""),
+   x=somestring
+   )
[1] "muxjvynzqh"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = as.data.frame(apply(df,2,function(x) gsub('Á|Ã', 'A', df)))
```

2 indicates columns and 1 indicates rows

Comment: This works for one "A" substitutions, but what about the rest? My point is: how can I do it without running the same command six times?

Comment: Please see agstudy's answer above, that works perfectly